# Creating an integer prompt using numbers between 32-126 on Python

Tags: python

So it looks like someone already asked this but they were not specific so they did not get a proper response. I am in a scripting class and we're learning to use Python. The whole question is:

"(1) Prompt the user to input an integer between 32 and 126, a float, a character, and a string, storing each into separate variables. Then, output those four values on a single line separated by a space."

What I am asking is how do I write the prompt to keep the integers between 32 and 126? We are using zyBooks and they don't do a very good job of explaining this, they provide the code, user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n')) but this does not "cap" the minimum and max allowed values.

Thanks in advance for any help, please be gentle in your responses, I'm new!

Comment: You can't magically cap the input. You must write some validation and re-ask the user the same question if the number is outside that range.

Answer (score 1):

Well this `user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))` only returns the integer *inputed*. So you must code it yourself, maybe as follows :

```
user_int = None
while True:
    user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))
    if 32 <= user_int <= 126: 
        break
```